# Updating Context State Values using Hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to follow [this guide](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-use-basic-react-hooks-for-context) on "how to use basic react hooks for context" and it is great at giving a basic structure to a context component but doesn't go into how one could update pieces without the default values returning.

I was trying to implement something like this

```
import React, { Component, useContext, useState } from 'react';

export const ProfileContext = React.createContext<ContextState | null>(null);

interface ContextState {
  changeInformation: Function
  team: string
  company: string
}

export const ProfileProvider = (props) => {
  const userInformation = {
    company: 'Progress',
    companyImage: 'https://svgshare.com/i/9ir.svg',
    url: 'https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/',
    userImage: 'https://i.imgur.com/Y1XRKLf.png',
    userName: 'Kendoken',
    fullName: 'Kendoken No Michi',
    team: 'KendoReact',
    // This sets all the initial values but changes the team.
    // I want to make a function that changes any property by name to the new value
    changeInformation: (property: string, value: any) => {
      let newInfo = {...userInfo}
      newInfo[property] = value
      setUserInfo(newInfo);
    }
  }

  // create `userInfo` with update method called `setUserInfo`
  // set default to `userInformation`
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(userInformation);
  return (
    <ProfileContext.Provider value={userInfo}>
      {props.children}
    </ProfileContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

For some reason, the default values return rather than the updated state after multiple updates. My child component looks like this:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { ProfileContext } from "../data"

export const ChangeTeam = () => {
    const context = useContext(ProfileContext);
    return (
      <>
        <button className="profile-button"
          onClick={() => context.changeInformation('team', 'Vue')}>Vue</button>
        <button className="profile-button"
          onClick={() => context.changeInformation('company', 'React')}>React</button>
        <p>Team: {context.team}</p>
        <p>Company: {context.company}</p>
      </>
    )
  }
```

I know that I am doing something wrong to have it recall the default values but I am not sure about the structure to fix this.

If you have any insight please let me know.

UPDATE - (I know the values are differnet) I have gotten this to work for my needs but I feel like there should be a cleaner way to manage this:

```
import React, { Component, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const ProfileContext = React.createContext<ContextState | null>(null);

interface ContextState {
    setCompany: Function
    setName: Function
    name: string
    company: string
}

export const ProfileProvider = (props: {children: HTMLElement}) => {
  const [company, setCompany] = useState('Progress');
  const [name, setName] = useState('Bill');

  return (
    <ProfileContext.Provider value={{company, setCompany, name, setName}}>
      {props.children}
    </ProfileContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

I would like to be able to dynamically add unknown items to the state that is why the first approach seems to do the trick slightly better but I am not sure.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and it seems to be working:

```
import React, { Component, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const ProfileContext = React.createContext<ContextState | null>(null);

interface ContextState {
  changeInformation: Function
  team: string
  company: string
  address: string
}

export const ProfileProvider = (props: {children: HTMLElement}) => {
  const userInformation = {
    company: 'Progress',
    companyImage: 'https://svgshare.com/i/9ir.svg',
    url: 'https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/',
    userImage: 'https://i.imgur.com/Y1XRKLf.png',
    userName: 'Kendoken',
    fullName: 'Kendoken No Michi',
    team: 'KendoReact',
    // This sets all the initial values but changes the team.
    // I want to make a function that changes any property by name to the new value
    changeInformation: (property: string, value: any) => {
      setUserInfo(prevInfo => ({
        ...prevInfo,
        [property]: value
      }) );
    }
  }

  // create `userInfo` with update method called `setUserInfo`
  // set default to `userInformation`
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(userInformation)

  return (
    <ProfileContext.Provider value={userInfo}>
      {props.children}
    </ProfileContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

It seems exactly like the demo but for some reason, I couldn't get the demo working. I think it is because I set it to the prevInfo instead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've solved your issue, but can I suggest reworking things slightly?
Ideally (to me) you'd keep your data pure, and I don't think there's a reason to have the update function in there anyway.

```
export const ProfileProvider = (props: { children: HTMLElement }) => {
  const userInformation = {
    company: 'Progress',
    companyImage: 'https://svgshare.com/i/9ir.svg',
  };

  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(userInformation)

  const changeInfo = (property: string, value: any) =>
    setUserInfo(prevInfo => ({ ...prevInfo, [property]: value }));

  return (
    <ProfileContext.Provider value={{ userInfo, changeInfo }}>
      {props.children}
    </ProfileContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const ChangeTeam = () => {
  const { userInfo, changeInfo } = useContext(ProfileContext);
  return (
    <>
      <button className="profile-button"
        onClick={() => changeInfo('team', 'Vue')}>Vue</button>
      <p>Team: {userInfo.team}</p>
    </>
  )
}
```